How could I correct the formula?
Formula:
If  A > B  And
   -B > -A 
  
Then A > -A ?

Now,
13 > 12
-12 > -13 (As 13 is bigger than 12. So negative of it will be alter)
So,  13 > - 13
But,
-13 > -14
14 > 13
So, - 13 > 13 should happen following previous formula.  How to correct the formula?

The shaded portion is not correct, and you have given a counterexample, and this is not [tag:linear-algebra]

Your assumption is only $A>B$, because this implies $-A<-B$. But from $A>B$ you cannot conclude $2A>0$ (which is $A>-A$), because the assumption doesn't say anything about the sign of $A$. So any negative $A$ will give you a counterexample.
